# Angular js directive controller function bind issue when using ng repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a code like this

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  $scope.hello = "hello"; 
  $scope.check = [1,2];

  $scope.focus1 = function(){
    $scope.setFocusInput0();    
  };
  $scope.focus2 = function(){
    $scope.setFocusInput1();    
  };
});

app.directive('rfocus',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
        var fooName = 'setFocus' + $attrs.rfocus; 
        $scope[fooName] = function(){alert(1)
            $element.focus();                
        } 
    },
  }    
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<input ng-repeat="i in check" type="checkbox" rfocus="Input{{$index}}"/>
<button ng-click="focus1()">set focus 1</button>
<button ng-click="focus2()">set focus 2</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2PJMQ/29/

When i removing ng-repeat and place checkboxes in static its working fine.

Comment: Where 's your `setFocusInput0` function and `setFocusInput1` function in your main controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At case of using directive with `ng-repeat`, you will have several nested scopes, so you should make some changes([plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/ztfd6tc0/2/)):

```
app.directive('rfocus',function(){
    return {
        scope:{
            rfocus:'@'
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            var fooName = 'setFocus' + $scope.rfocus;                          
            $scope.$parent.$parent[fooName] = function(){
                alert(1)
                $element.focus();                
            } 
        },
    }    
});
```

Or this [variant](http://jsfiddle.net/2PJMQ/31/):

```
<input ng-repeat="i in check" type="checkbox" rfocus="'Input' + $index"/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
app.directive('rfocus',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){        
            var fooName = 'setFocus' + $scope.$eval($attrs.rfocus);
            $scope.$parent.$parent[fooName] = function(){
                    alert(1)
                $element.focus();                
            } 
        },
    }    
});
```

But both of them will not work at plain situation. I think better [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ztfd6tc0/1/) is to change initial approach. You should pass to each directive it's identifier, i.e. `rfocus` and reference to variable `focus`, which determines current focused element, so you can change this variable in your controller and then directives will reflect it:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input ng-repeat="i in check" type="checkbox" rfocus="{{$index}}" focus='{{focus}}'/>
    <button ng-click="focusClick(0)">set focus 1</button>
    <button ng-click="focusClick(1)">set focus 2</button>
    <input type="checkbox" rfocus="2" focus='{{focus}}'/>
    <button ng-click="focusClick(2)">set focus 3</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.hello = "hello"; 
    $scope.check = [1,2];
    $scope.focus = 0;

    $scope.focusClick = function(index){    
        $scope.focus = index;
    };    
});

app.directive('rfocus',function(){
    return {        
        scope:{
           rfocus:'@',
           focus:'@'
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){            
            $scope.$watch('focus', function(){                  
                if($scope.rfocus == $scope.focus)
                    $element.focus();                
            }); 
        },
    }    
});
```